# Qemu - Pass tty device from host to guest machine

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, tty

My goal is to pass a tty device from the host to guest in Qemu.

I'm trying to emulate a ARM64 linux device using Qemu that has a USB-CDC device plugged into it.  So far, I have emulated said USB-CDC device by passing simulated data via UDP to a pts device on my host machine like so:

```
sudo socat -d -d UDP-L:14550 pty,link=/dev/ttyFAKEACM0,raw,echo=0
```

I can use minicom on the host machine to read ttyACM0 and I get the data I expect.

I want to pass /dev/ttyFAKEACM0 on the host machine to the guest Qemu and have it show up as a tty on the guest.  I have attempted to use -chardev like so:

```
  qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -m 4G \
  -smp 4 \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -M virt -nographic \
  -kernel ${IMGDIR}/Image \
  -initrd ${IMGDIR}/uInitrd-5.7.0 \
  -append "root=/dev/vda1 serial=tty0 ubootpart=00000000-01 console=ttyAMA0,115200n8 rootwait init=/sbin/init rw earlyprintk rootfstype=ext4" \
  -drive if=none,id=mmc0,file=${IMGDIR}/edge-rootfs.img,index=1,format=raw \
  -device virtio-blk-device,drive=mmc0 \
  -chardev tty,path=/dev/ttyFAKEACM0,id=facm \
  -device pci-serial,chardev=facm
```

When i start Qemu ttyFAKEACM0 does not show up at all in the guest.  Am I misunderstanding how chardev works?  How can pass a character device from the host to guest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to pass through a TTY device from host to guest. In my case it is a USB adapter, controller.

I had success using the Qemu [USB emulation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/devices/usb.html):

```
-chardev serial,path=/dev/ttyACM0,id=acm \
-usb -device usb-serial,chardev=acm
```

The USB was captured by the guest as `ttyUSB0`.

If running as any other user than "root" then you may need to adjust the permissions to the device. In my case I created a special group for the adapter, controller and adjusted the permission accordingly; `chmod g+rw /dev/ttyACM0`.